# Fraction transformation

Tags: fractions

I am not sure how it is possible to write $\frac{\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}+1}{\sqrt{t^2+1}+t}$ as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}$ Does anyone know how I can transform this? I would appriciate a step-by-step solution.

Comment: Simplify the numerator. You will see immediately how the result was obtained.

Comment: ok, done thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}+1}{\sqrt{t^2+1}+t}=\frac{\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}+\frac{\sqrt{t^2+1}}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}}{\sqrt{t^2+1}+t}=\frac{\frac{t+\sqrt{t^2+1}}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}}{\sqrt{t^2+1}+t}=\frac{t+\sqrt{t^2+1}}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+1}+t}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}$$

Comment: Thanks @MathLover, I thought it would not fit well with the double dollar.